# Displaying a string which may contain a field needing filled in. Split segues or better solution?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm writing my first iOS/Xcode App for iPhone and therefore lack the experience with the tools to make the right decision regarding the next design/development step in my project.

I have almost 100 questions of varying length which are all static strings with several exceptions.
The exceptions require the input of a single word (a name) within the string.
e.g.
"What sort food does [NAME] like to eat?"

My question is what is the most elegant way of implementing this in XCode 4.5 for the iPhone (iPad to come later)?

I'm using storyboards (which are great for beginners such as myself).
Do I do a pre-segue check for [NAME] and split to 2 different possible views.
One which simply displays the static string questions and the other makes use of static label(s) along with an input text field?

Or is there a simpler way that I've not seen of doing this using the Cocoa Touch API?

Comment: "I'm using storyboards (which are great for beginners such as myself)" - actually, if you're a beginner, you better learn how to make UIs programmatically or later you'll be missing important architectural and practical informations about how the view system, drawing, hierarchy, etc. works.

Comment: Indeed, once I've got an iOS6 version for iPhone complete and working I'll then look at xib's and pre-4.2/storyboard development for compatibility with earlier versions. That can wait for now. In the meantime I'd like to get a working v1.0.

Comment: This seems like a good question, however it isn't clear what you are trying to do with the two different types of screens.  Can you add an example of what the two different cases would look like to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already know if and where the question has to be divided. What I would do is insert a symbol into every question representing the missing part. When generating the UI I would split the question string into several parts, creating an UILabels for the question parts and replacing the missing part symbols with a UITextFields.

I think this is the easiest and clearest way to implement it.

Comment: Yes this seems the obvious way to me. Not knowing XCode/Cocoa-touch that well I put this question up to see if there was another way. This is what I've coded up so far (in the time since I posted the question). Why "several parts"? Are you suggesting a UILabel for each word? I'm confused...